# Backbone JS Button to open a new view, save values in form

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Im new to backbone and I'm looking to a very simple 2 view configuration page usig backbone.

I have the following code;

```
define(
  ["backbone","...","..."],
    function(Backbone, ... , ... )  {
      var PopupView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function initialize() {
          Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.apply(this,arguments);
        },

        events: {
          "click .save_conf_button": "save_conf",
        },

        render: function() {
          this.el.innerHTML = this.get_popup_template();
          return this;
        },

        save:conf: function save_conf() {
          //get the field values from popup_template
          //var items = jquery(....);
      });

      var ExampleView = Backbone.View.extend({
        //Starting view
        initialize: function initialize() {
          Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        },

        events: {
          "click .setup_button": "trigger_setup", //Triggers final setup
          "click .create_conf_button": "trigger_popup_setup", //This is the conf popup 
        },


        render: function() {
          this.el.innerHTML = this.get_start_html();
          return this;
        },


        trigger_popup_setup: function trigger_popup_setup() {
          console.log("Pop up");
          //this.el.innerHTML = this.get_popup_template();
          PopupView.render();
          ...
        },
      }); //End of exampleView
  return ExampleView;
 } // end of require asynch
); // end of require
```

E.g. The ExampleView is the starting view with a couple of fields and 2 buttons; create popup and save. Upon pressing the create_conf_button I want to render the popup view, however this does not seem to work as I expected. (`Uncaught TypeError: PopupView.render is not a function`)

I'm not sure how to proceed and additionally what the "best practice" is for generating these types of dialogs?
Additionally, keeping the values filled in on the previous page after returning from the popupview would be preferential.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `initialize: function initialize() {
          Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
},`
Why are you dong this?

`save:conf:` this looks like invalid syntax?

Comment: And your views seem to be invoking methods like `this.get_popup_template()`, `this.get_start_html()` but they are not defined...

Comment: Also since you are using AMD module pattern, please keep the modules DRY - create separate modules for `PopupView` and `ExampleView`. Having many things in one module beats the purpose of a "module" system...

Answer (score 2):

try

```
new PopupView.render()
```

you have to create an instance to call the methods this way

Comment: Im using require.js, so I dont know how to `return PopupView` -- How do I properly make PopupView into a constructor to be able to use `new` ?

Comment: Just return popupview

Comment: I can't seem to do that since everything is defined within the `define()` codeword. Please tell me if there's a way of breaking up the different views or similar.

Answer (score 2):

@ashish is correct, you have to instantiate an instance of the PopupView before calling its render method. Currently, you have defined a blueprint for a view called PopupView, which will act as a constructor for newly created PopupView view instances. In order to use this defined view I would suggest storing it in ExampleView's render or initialize method:

```
// Example View's initialize method
initialize: function initialize() {
   this.popUpView = new PopupView();
   Backbone.View.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
```

},

then referencing it in your trigger_popup_setup function as follows:

```
trigger_popup_setup: function trigger_popup_setup() {
    console.log("Pop up");
    //this.el.innerHTML = this.get_popup_template();
    this.popUpView.render();
    ...
},
```

As for storing state Backbone models are used for that :)

In general to **nest subviews within a master view** in Backbone you can do the following:

```
initialize : function () {
    //...
},

render : function () {

    this.$el.empty();

    this.innerView1 = new Subview({options});
    this.innerView2 = new Subview({options});

    this.$('.inner-view-container')
        .append(this.innerView1.el)
        .append(this.innerView2.el);
}
```

In this example the master view is creating instances of it's subviews within its render method and attaching them to a corresponding DOM element.

Comment: Hi Nathan. I've added code that shows how everything is enclosed in the "define" codeword, I don't know how to make 2 `return` statements in this manner of writing. I'm relatively new to modern javascsript. Can you elaborate on how I can return 2 views in 1 function declaration?

Comment: Hi enrm, you're creating a nested view where PopupView is a nested subview within ExampleView so you would only have to return ExampleView. ExampleView would have a reference to it's nested subview, in this case this.popUpView, so when the user clicks the .create_conf_button button ExampleView will  trigger the rendering its subview: popUpView.

Comment: Updated my answer so you can see general nesting strategy for backbone views since as a comment the code wasn't nicely formatted. Hopefully, that helps!

Comment: Ah of course. Will try it out. Thanks for taking your time!

Comment: I don't know, I can't get it to work. why can't I just do this.el.innerHTML = this.get_popup_template() ? I mean it works - what am I losing with this?

Comment: @enrm the code you shared in question does not have a `get_popup_template()` method

Comment: Sorry. `render: function() {
          this.el.innerHTML = this.get_popup_template();` The contents of the template are pretty  uninmportant as it's only html

Comment: The purpose of the Backbonejs is to give you the benefits of MV* on the client-side and to leverage known design patterns for your front-end development. Check out https://github.com/tastejs/todomvc/tree/master/examples/backbone for an example of how to structure your application properly for separation of concerns. Ideally, you will further modularize through the use of require/AMD but the most important part is to get a working app first then optimize and refactor as necessary. To see the example app in action visit http://todomvc.com/examples/backbone/#/

Comment: If you found my answer useful, please consider accepting it :)